# unique legend in subplots (matplotlib)

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I'm trying to create 5 subplots in the format of (2,3) with (1,3) being empty space, where I want to place the legend. There are six lines in each subplot and I want to make legend for this.
I got the subplots, with the right format but am having a hard time to get:

(1) unique legend; with fig.legend(), the legend is full of duplicated lines, I want to create the legend purely based on the name of the line;
(2) place the legend in the empty space of subplot (1,3).

Your help is appreciated.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,3)

for i, j in zip(g_list,c_list):
        axs[0,0].plot(global_epsilon_T()["g_"+i+"_vlt"], global_epsilon_T()["g_"+i],   color=j, linewidth=1, label = "(c) "+i)
        axs[0,1].plot(global_epsilon_B()["g_"+i+"_vlt"], global_epsilon_B()["g_"+i],   color=j, linewidth=1, label = "(c) "+i)
        axs[0,2].plot(global_slope()["g_"+i+"_vlt"], global_slope()["g_"+i],   color=j, linewidth=1, label = "(c) "+i)
        axs[1,0].plot(global_trb()["g_"+i+"_vlt"], global_trb()["g_"+i],   color=j, linewidth=1, label = "(c) "+i)
        axs[1,1].plot(global_dis()["g_"+i+"_vlt"], global_dis()["g_"+i],   color=j, linewidth=1, label = "(c) "+i)

axs[1,2].set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attribute the legend to each subplot by doing `axs[i,j].legend()` and have a legend for each plot showing the label for that subplot. If you want to have all the labels on subplot (1,3) do the following and pass into it the handles and the labels you want it to display:

```
axs[1,3].legend([ax for ax in axs],[label for label in listOfLabels])
```

Alternatively, you can attribute it to the figure so have `plt.legend()` after your for loop and it should display a legend with all the labels on the figure object not the subplots.

Also, are you not getting an error with this: `label = "(c) "+i`
perhaps try `label = "(c)%i" %(i)`